# How to Hide TextView when Scrolling Recycler View?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am devoloping an app interface for a local data base. In the fragment I intend to show the client's information, I want to be able to see the client's history. How can I hide the clients information when scrolling the client's history? (How can I hide several Text Views when scrolling a recyclerview in order to that recyclerview occupies the all screen?)

None of the solutions I encontered online really solve my problem. I am new to android so I am sure this is something farely simple.

[What I Have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5c4po.png)

[What I Want when I scroll far enough](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdrdC.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_layout">


        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/bt_add_history"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorTextGrey"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:hoveredFocusedTranslationZ="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:maxImageSize="24dp"
            app:useCompatPadding="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title_hist"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_semibold"
            android:text="@string/historico"
            android:textColor="#67739A"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_obser" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_obser"
            style="@style/CustomEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/observations"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_title_observ" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title_observ"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_semibold"
            android:text="@string/observations"
            android:textColor="#67739A"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_func" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_func"
            style="@style/CustomEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/func"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_phone_number" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_phone_number"
            style="@style/CustomEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/telemovel"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_birth_date" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_birth_date"
            style="@style/CustomEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/dataNascimento"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_nome" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_nome"
            style="@style/CustomEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/nome"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_history"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_title_hist" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

**EDIT**:

With the help of [Md. Asaduzzaman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2637449/md-asaduzzaman), I ended up with this code for de xml (notice the changes to the action button - I wanted it to float above everything):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/bt_add_history"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorTextGrey"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:hoveredFocusedTranslationZ="0dp"
            app:maxImageSize="24dp"
            app:useCompatPadding="false"/>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_layout">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title_hist"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_semibold"
            android:text="@string/historico"
            android:textColor="#67739A"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_obser" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_obser"
            style="@style/CustomEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/observations"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_title_observ" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title_observ"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_semibold"
            android:text="@string/observations"
            android:textColor="#67739A"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_func" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_func"
            style="@style/CustomEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/func"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_phone_number" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_phone_number"
            style="@style/CustomEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/telemovel"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_birth_date" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_birth_date"
            style="@style/CustomEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/dataNascimento"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_nome" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_nome"
            style="@style/CustomEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/nome"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_history"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_title_hist" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</layout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `NestedScrollView` to make the whole view scrollable, which hides the top view when you start scrolling.

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_layout">


        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/bt_add_history"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorTextGrey"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:hoveredFocusedTranslationZ="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:maxImageSize="24dp"
            app:useCompatPadding="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title_hist"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_semibold"
            android:text="@string/historico"
            android:textColor="#67739A"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_obser" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_obser"
            style="@style/CustomEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/observations"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_title_observ" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title_observ"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_semibold"
            android:text="@string/observations"
            android:textColor="#67739A"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_func" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_func"
            style="@style/CustomEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/func"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_phone_number" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_phone_number"
            style="@style/CustomEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/telemovel"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_birth_date" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_birth_date"
            style="@style/CustomEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/dataNascimento"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_nome" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_nome"
            style="@style/CustomEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/nome"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_history"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_title_hist" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response! Worked like a **charm**!! Thank you so much!

Comment: Actually, I think that this make problems for performance of RecyclerView. Imagine that initially you will send to its adapter more than hundreds items and because of the NestedScrollView, all items will be processed and all viewholders will be created.